# Programming for the iPhone with a partner far away?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I program for the iPhone with my friend who lives very far away?  After I fix something, do I have to send the whole thing over to him and again and again and again? Any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Not to jerk it up too much, but the premise of this question leads me to believe that you may be better served focusing more on learning basic programming skills before an Version Control System would even be useful to you. I hate to see you get caught up in choosing an SCM system when you aren't really sure what the pros and cons of each are or how to use them properly. It is time that may be better spent building a strong foundation in Cocoa/Objective-C.

Comment: well I am in the middle of learning c, and was just wondering how that would be possible when I move to objective  and start build applications with my buddy. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use a SCM(Source Code Management) system. XCode has support for CVS and/or SubVersion, so you could set that up.

Answer (score 3):

You some kind of version control system (Subversion, GIT or whatever) that will help you easily merge your changes.

If you change something your friend will just update his sources and will see your changes and vice versa. Using version control is also a good idea if you are the only programmer in the project as you can always easily revert your changes, always have the full history etc.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum requirement is to make your code available from both sides and find a way to prevent conflicts. This is achieved with a SCM server. I have already successfully tried [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/) and [www.beanstalkapp.com](http://www.beanstalkapp.com/) with Xcode, but many others exist.

Moreover, you may need an issue tracking server. My personal choice is [www.lighthouseapp.com](http://www.lighthouseapp.com/) which integrates with [www.beanstalkapp.com](http://www.beanstalkapp.com/). Also here many alternatives are available.

Finally, don't forget basic communication with phone and e-mail.

Comment: No. At least not the ones I know (Clearcase, CVS, SVN).

Answer (score 2):

Use GitHub.  They have excellent documentation and git is nice to work with for distributed work.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for http://www.beanstalkapp.com, with http://www.versionsapp.com for posting and getting updates.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, a Version Control System, I prefer git, but subversion will also work, and some form of communication. I'm sure you already have e-mail, and instant messaging might work, but I've found that communicating through some form of VOIP software increases productivity, such as Skype.